# On modifying the gradient in gradient descent when the objective function is not convex nor does it have Lipschitz gradient.

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

It is well know that if one wants to perform gradient descent on a function $f(x)$ the ideal conditions would be those of strong convexity and Lipschitz continuous gradient, i. e.,
$$ 0 <\ell \le \nabla^2 f(x) \le L $$
for $\ell, L  \in \mathbb{R}$.

Assume Instead we have a function $g(x)$ that does not have Lipschitz continuous gradient nor is strongly convex but we know its gradient $\nabla g(x)$ and that it has a (unique) minimum in $x^*$.

Could we perform gradient descent successfully utilizing as a gradient $h(x) \nabla g(x)$, where $h(x)$ is a function that shares the support of $g(x)$ and is s.t.  $h(x^*) \nabla g(x^*) = 0$  (only at $x^*$) and

$$  0 <\ell \le \nabla (h(x) \nabla g(x)) \le L ,$$

instead of just $\nabla g(x)$.

That is utilizing as an iterative optimization scheme

$$  x_{k+1} = x_k + \alpha h(x_k) \nabla g(x_k) $$

where $\alpha < 2 / L$ instead of

$$  x_{k+1} = x_k + \alpha  \nabla g(x_k) $$

Comment: What is $h(x)$?

Comment: @SungheeYun I edited to make it clearer.

Comment: This is akin to preconditioned gradient descent methods like here: http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~fessler/book/c-opt.pdf ?

Answer (score 0):

I do know believe we can find such a function $h$ to make $h(x)\nabla g(x)$ be a gradient of a strongly convex function. Here's my argument.

We can find an optimization problem which is not possible to solve. For examples, solving an optimization problem minimizing a general $10$th-order polynomial with $10$ variables is impossible. We know that it has (unique) global optimum $x^\ast$, but do not know how to solve it (in a reasonable amount of time). If we COULD find such $h(x)$, the original problem $g(x)$ WOULD be solvable, which is a contradiction!

Comment: my guess is that you got downvoted because the question states that you have to know the gradient of $g$, and I cannot think of an NP-hard problem for which that is the case

Comment: @LinAlg Good point, but it doesn't have to be a NP hard. there are lots and lots of non-convex optimization problem whose global solution cannot be found. For example, a general 5th degree polynomial with 10 variables cannot be minimized in polynomial time. So my argument is very strong IF the reader knows this basic fact.

Comment: @LinAlg But your advice is useful here. I'll edit my answer a bit. Thx for your comments!